# How can I insert spaces or characters every "n" spaces while tailing a file?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I am tailing a log file and want to make it more readable.

The current output is something like this:

```
HH:MM:SS.ss CONTROL:00011100001110101010111000000000
HH:MM:SS.ss INDICATION:00000001110101001111010101011011
```

I want the output to be more like this:

```
HH:MM:SS.ss CONTROL:00011100 00111010 10101110 00000000
HH:MM:SS.ss INDICATION:00000001 11010100 11110101 01011011
```

It would be great if `sed` could be used to insert the spaces.

The spaces need to be every 8 characters — it will always be in binary data after the last `:` in octets (but the octets are missing the spaces I want to see).

Comment: `tail -f growingFile | perl -pe 's/(\d{8})(?=\d)/$1 /g'` <--I think this'll do it

Comment: This also works for my needs, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works with both GNU and BSD (macOS) versions of `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/^\(.*:\([01]\{8\} \)*\)\([01]\{8\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1\3 \4/' -e 't a'
```

Given the data file:

```
HH:MM:SS.ss CONTROL:00011100001110101010111000000000
HH:MM:SS.ss INDICATION:00000001110101001111010101011011
17:49:23.96 MODIFIED:0100010010101010101101010101010101001010101010111110100010011101
```

it gives the output:

```
HH:MM:SS.ss CONTROL:00011100 00111010 10101110 00000000
HH:MM:SS.ss INDICATION:00000001 11010100 11110101 01011011
17:49:23.96 MODIFIED:01000100 10101010 10110101 01010101 01001010 10101011 11101000 10011101
```

The first `-e` command creates a label `a`; the third jumps to the label `a` if the commands in between made a substitution (it's a loop in `sed`).  The fun is all in the middle command:

```
s/^\(.*:\([01]\{8\} \)*\)\([01]\{8\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1\3 \4/
```

The `\(…\)` notation captures information that can be referred to with `\n` in the replacement clause.  They can nest, too.  The `\{8\}` requires 8 (in this case) of the previous unit.  The previous unit is `[01]`, the binary digits.

Overall, it captures everything up to the last colon `:` plus 0 or more units of 8 binary digits followed by a blank (and captures all this as `\1`; there's also a `\2` in there, but I don't use it), plus one unit of 8 binary digits (captured as `\3`) followed by a non-blank (captured as `\4`).  It replaces them with `\1\3 \4`.

Because the `\4` needs to be part of the next sequence of 8 binary digits, you need the looping rather than a `g` modifier on the substitute command.

FWIW: I wrote the code in a file `sed.script` containing:

```
:a
s/^\(.*:\([01]\{8\} \)*\)\([01]\{8\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1\3 \4/
t a
```

and then ran:

```
sed -f sed.script data
```

That can sometimes be a useful technique.  Here, it's not critical, but it can simplify life, especially if you need to process quotes — single, double, back quotes — in the sed script.  The file is not affected by the shell interpreting the contents of the regexes.

Comment: This...uh, makes me think there must be something wrong my "comment answer" :)  (not a smartass comment...It really makes me think that)

Comment: @zzxyz: Yes, no, maybe.  Perl is an alternative; I like it and use it, but I also like and use `sed`.  Your code is a bit sloppier — it doesn't insist on binary digits and allows sequences of decimal digits; that probably isn't a show stopper.  The lookahead that's available in Perl makes life easier as it allows the `g` modifier to work without requiring the explicit looping that `sed` requires.  People are a bit leery of Perl — it might not always be on production machines, whereas `sed` is required by POSIX and is seldom missing (except perhaps on Windows).  You Perl fragment works fine.

Comment: @zzxyz: If there were 9 or more consecutive digits before the colon, your Perl code would map those with spaces too.  It is unlikely to be an actual problem given the data format — it would require the 'label' to include 9+ digits, which is probably implausible.

Comment: Yeah, that last bit did occur to me.  In addition to potential flushing problems, which it looks like `sed -f ` would handle.  Ah never mind...just a script flag.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the straightforward feedback.  ps--as a mostly Windows guy, I would be *very* shocked if a bash install didn't include `perl` (mingw, ghetto `git` consoles, etc)..however if it didn't include `sed` I would probably not even consider it bash.

Comment: Thank you, that is really cool.  I will have to read through this a few times.  One issue I had though.  I was getting an error running my script, and I made a change that seems to work. There was a ` instead of a ' near the end right after the 4.

Comment: @Diego: Thanks!